# Azure python function V2 queue size not honored

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure python function with a queue size of 1 and it seems to be processing more than 1 message at a time. Here is my host.json

I've tried changing the extension bundle to 4.x,5.0.0 but, it's not helped

I've gone through the documentation to no help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#example

```
 
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 1,
      "messageEncoding": "base64"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic concurrency

The Azure Queue storage trigger has its own message polling loop. When using static config, concurrency is governed by the BatchSize/NewBatchThreshold config options. **When using dynamic concurrency, those configuration values are ignored.** Dynamic concurrency is integrated into the message loop, so the number of messages fetched per iteration are dynamically adjusted. When throttles are enabled (host is overloaded), message processing will be paused until throttles are disabled. When throttles are disabled, concurrency will increase.

The solution was to remove dynamic concurrency from my host.json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-concurrency